# Selenium - Button Clicks

Tags: python, selenium

How can I click on buttons that are on the same page (not at the same time), but each click on them takes me to a different page?

I tried something like that:

1. get list of buttons in the same page.

   2. for every button in the list:
   3. click on it
   4. do some scraping...
   5. go to prev page

the problem is... after I go back and forth between the pages for the first time, the button list no longer recognized

So Then I tried something like that and it works:

1. get number of buttons in the same page:

   2. for i in range(len(buttons)):
   3. get list of buttons and from there take the i-th one
   4. click on the i-th button
   5. do some scraping...
   6. go to prev page

on the one hand, it makes sence why I can't do something like my first code,
on the other hand, there's gotta be a better way rather then that...

Comment: When you go back you have to get buttons again, if you read error message it will help you and help us when you do question

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your code, you error should explain that buttons elements aren't on DOM

```
buttons = get_buttons

for i in range(len(buttons)):

    click on the button[i]

    do some scraping...

    go to prev page

    buttons = get_buttons
```